# How to set a timeout before showing a dialog Android?

Tags: java, android, timeout

I am trying to show a dialog I have made but before I need to set a timeout before showing it, like you do with the setTimeout function in javascript. Is there a way to do this in Android with java?

I have tried to use a Timer instance but when the code is executed I get this exception:

```
03-19 22:18:19.638: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
03-19 22:18:19.638: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create       
handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

This is the code:

```
            // instantiating a new CustomDialog class
            MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog(thisContext, R.layout.institutional_info_custom_list);
            DetailListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_list);
            final MasterDetailArrayAdapter adapter = new MasterDetailArrayAdapter(ComeHaInvestito.this, MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList);         
            DetailListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            final MyCustomDialog showDialog = dialog;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showDialog.show();
                }
            }, 600);
```

what am I mistaking? I read that the dialog is bound to the Acrivity class so maybe putting the showDialog.show() call in the new TimerClass() makes it throw the exception?

By the way, what is the best way to perform actions like the one I have described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what am I mistaking? I read that the dialog is bound to the Acrivity
>   class so maybe putting the showDialog.show() call in the new
>   TimerClass() makes it throw the exception?

Problem is that `TimerTask` **runs on background Thread** - hence that problem `->` you cannot call whatever that will change UI state (for example showing Dialog) from background Thread. 
Instead that use `Handler` with postDelayed() method:

Pseudo-code:

```
int counter = 0;
...
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

   public void run() {

       // it will be > 0 when run() will be called twice
       if (counter > 0) {
           dlg.show();

           // it made a trick now remove callbacks from Handler and return
           handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
           return;
       }

       counter++;
       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 600);

   }
};
runnable.run();
```

This approach is cleaner than a possible usage of `runOnUiThread()` construction and can be called for example periodically with slight modification.

Comment: Yes I guessed it was because of that, now I have added to my code the runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {}); and it works. You suggest me to do the same thing with an Handler, how can I do that?

Comment: @user3019105 look at updated answer. I addded simple example.